# How to decode unnecessarily url-encoded characters in a URL?

Tags: regex, awk, utf-8, urlencode

Now I'm working on Wikipedia. In many articles, I noticed some URLs, for example, https://www.google.com/search?q=%26%E0%B8%89%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%99, are very long. The example URL can be replaced with "https://www.google.com/search?q=%26ฉัน" (ฉัน is a Thai word) which is shorter and cleaner. However, when I use urllib.unquote function to decode URL, it decodes even %26 and get "https://www.google.com/search?q=&ฉัน" as the result. As you might have noticed, this URL is useless; it doesn't make a valid link.

Therefore, I want to know how to get decode link while it is valid. I think that decoding only non-ascii character would get the valid URL. Is it correct? and how to do that?

This question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857253/decode-url-only-non-ascii-character) about 9 years ago. As it does not have a satisfactory answer, I’ve resubmitted it.

Comment: A question not having satisfactory answers is not a valid reason to re-post it. You can start a bounty to encourage new/improved answers to the existing question instead.

Comment: Note that `...?q=&ฉัน` is an invalid URL; URLs can't contain non-ASCII chars…

Comment: @deceze They can. Check out https://maktabkhooneh.org/course/هنر-حل-مسئله-با-داده-mk1097/

Comment: That's your browser being generous and implicitly encoding and decoding the URL for you. If you look at the actual network request, it's all `%...` encoded, because that needs to be an actual, valid URL.

Comment: @deceze: that's just how the browser decides to accept and display URLs. But in the HTTP request these kinds of URLs **must** be URL-encoded.